# Doctrine ORM semantical query error: Class has no association

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, repository-pattern

Getting a somewhat abstract error, the repository and entity relationship mappings seem to be correct:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 102 near 'v WHERE t.domainName': Error: 
    Class AppBundle\Entity\DocumentVersion has no association named document_versions
```

The `Document` entity:

```
/**
 * @var Collection|DocumentVersion[]
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=DocumentVersion::class, mappedBy="document")
 **/
private $document_versions;
```

The `DocumentVersion` entity:

```
/**
 * @var Document
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=\AppBundle\Entity\Document::class, inversedBy="document_versions")
 * @JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
private $document;
```

Everything seems to be defined correctly. What is causing this error?

Comment: See that you answered your question already. As a side-question for you: why do you make your entity properties `private` instead of `protected`? I always make mine `protected` so as to be able to use them through inheritance. Was wondering if you used `private` with a specific reason.

Comment: I tend to leave things `private` until I know I want to expose them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers to the same error provide relationship configuration solutions which weren't applicable to my situation. Instead, after checking that the `app.repository.document_version` definition was correct:

```
app.repository.document_version:
    class: AppBundle\Repository\DocumentVersionRepository
    factory: ['@doctrine', getRepository]
    arguments: ['AppBundle\Entity\DocumentVersion']
```

It turned out it was the configuration of the repository relationship in the `DocumentVersion` entity class:

```
/**
 * DocumentVersion
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="document_version")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\DocumentRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 */
class DocumentVersion
```

Operative line:

```
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\DocumentRepository")
```

Note how, in the just above line, it's pointing to the wrong repository. Once it was updated to:

```
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\DocumentVersionRepository")
```

This resolved the issue. Also, within Symfony(3.3), the actual DQL it was borking on was a scroll down the screen in a second exception:

```
SELECT d 
FROM AppBundle\Entity\DocumentVersion d 
INNER JOIN d.tenant t 
INNER JOIN d.document_versions v 
WHERE t.domainName = :domain_name 
ORDER BY d.name ASC
```

Hopefully this keeps someone from spinning their wheels unnecessarily. `:)`